# FusedLocationApi coordinate system. is this use WGS84?

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I use FusedLocationApi and get location information

mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
mLastLocation.getLatitude(), 
mLastLocation.getLongitude()

problem is I don't know coordinate System. any google document no mention coordinate system.

My client want to get exactly evidence for fusedLocation use WGS84.

or

fusedLocation has not any coordinate?  no coordinate?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/what-is-the-projection-of-an-android-location-class-instance

Answer (score 0):

Fusedlocationprovider is location via  GPS and whatever is available.  cell towers, wifi spots, dead reckoning with the phone sensors.   Wifi is useful inside a warehouse retailer like Lowe's.  Dead reckoning on long straight roads or train tracks.  It returns a latitude longitude position.  When you calculate distance between two latitude longitude points you have to account for curvature of Earth.

WGS84 is for locations that move like Larson Shelf B which I heard might break off of Antarctica.  If there was a flag pole on a iceberg you could find that flag pole no mater where the iceberg was with WGS84.